@kubernetes/client-node The "original" argument must be of type function
I trying to run an existing node application that uses @kubernetes/client-node. When the application runs, it throws an error mentioned below:
internal/util.js:214
    throw new errors.TypeError('ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE', 'original', 'function');
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "original" argument must be of type function
    at promisify (internal/util.js:214:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/src/node_modules/get-stream/index.js:7:35)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/src/node_modules/execa/lib/stream.js:3:19)

I have been trying to resolve the issue but not sure what's wrong.
@kubernetes/client-node uses execa which further uses get-srream npm module
Environment information:
"@kubernetes/client-node": "0.17.0"

node -v
v10.24.1

npm -v
6.14.12

